# Is it possible to run out of gas in a method before reaching the self-destruct call?

Tags: solidity, out-of-gas, selfdestruct

I'd like to implement a self-destruct method for a smart contract that pools money from people as a last resort.

Before calling self-destruct, I'd like to refund all the money to the users and send whatever is remaining to the owner address.

I'm thinking of something along the lines of

```
uint256 usersLength = users.length;
for (var i = 0; i < usersLength; i++ ) {
    address user = users[i];
    uint256 refundAmount = pooledMoney[user];
    user.transfer(refundAmount);
)
selfdestruct(owner);
```

I'm a little worried what would happen if the size of the `users` array is very large, will the method run out of gas within the loop?

If so, what are alternative solutions for implementing something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the transaction will run out of gas if the array of users is too big.

The alternative is for each user to retrieve its part of the pool.

```
function withdraw() public {
    uint refundAmount = pooledMoney[msg.sender];
    if (refundAmount > 0) {
        pooledMoney[msg.sender] = 0;
        msg.sender.transfer(refundAmount);
        emit Refunded(msg.sender, refundAmount);
    }
}
```

After all users have withdraw their ether then the owner can destruct the contract.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Was wondering if their was an efficient way to do this on the users' behalf, but I guess there isn't...